# Form "Required" validation using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, validation

I want to show the error message of required if mandatory fields are left blank. I implement it using the following way but every time the function checkinput() is invoked it adds a new span element due to which "required" message is outputted multiple times. I want the span element to be added once and disappears when user fills in the requirement. Here is my code.

```js
const checkinput=(event)=>{
        if(event.target.value===""){
            event.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<span class="text-danger">Required</span>')
        }
        if(event.target.value!==""){
            var child=document.querySelector('span');
            child.remove();
        }
        

    }
    document.getElementById("username").addEventListener('blur',checkinput);
    document.getElementById("password").addEventListener('blur',checkinput);
    document.getElementById("confirmPassword").addEventListener('blur',checkinput);
```

Comment: try jquery validator it's easy to handle optional, mandatory fields and you don't need to create element for error message. https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Answer (score 2):

Reason why new `span` element is added each time you have a empty input field is because you are calling `insertAdjacentHTML` each time and inserting a new `span` element.

What you should do is add `span` elements with each input field in the html and initially they should be empty.When you want to validate the input fields, if any of the input is empty, select the `span` element next to that input element and show the error message in that `span` element using `.textContent` property. To clear the error message, you just need to set `.textContent` of the `span` element to an empty string.

Following code snippets show different ways of validating form inputs.

#### Form validation on form submit

Following code snippet validates form inputs when form is submitted.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const usernameError = document.querySelector('#usernameError');
const passwordError = document.querySelector('#passwordError');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const usernameValid = validateField(form, 'username', usernameError);
  const passwordValid = validateField(form, 'password', passwordError);

  if (usernameValid && passwordValid) {
    console.log('form submitted');
    form.reset();
  }
});

function validateField(form, fieldName, errorEl) {
  if (form.elements[fieldName].value == '') {
    errorEl.textContent = `${fieldName} is required`;
    return false;
  } else {
    errorEl.textContent = '';
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
form div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}

form label { margin: 0 0 5px; }
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <span id="usernameError"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <span id="passwordError"></span>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Form validation on input focus loose

Following code snippet validates form inputs when any of the input looses focus.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const inputsContainer = document.getElementById('formInputsContainer');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('button');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const usernameValid = validateField(form, 'username');
  const passwordValid = validateField(form, 'password');

  if (usernameValid && passwordValid) {
    console.log('form submitted');
    form.reset();
  }
});

submitBtn.addEventListener('focus', () => {
  form.requestSubmit();
});

inputsContainer.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
  validateField(form, event.target.name);
});

function validateField(form, fieldName) {
  const errorEl = document.getElementById(`${fieldName}Error`);

  if (form.elements[fieldName].value == '') {
    errorEl.textContent = `${fieldName} is required`;
    return false;
  } else {
    errorEl.textContent = '';
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
form div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}

form label { margin: 0 0 5px; }
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="formInputsContainer">
    <div>
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <span id="usernameError"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <span id="passwordError"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

#### Form validation as user types in the input field

Following code snippet validates form input as user types in any input field.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const inputsContainer = document.getElementById('formInputsContainer');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const usernameValid = validateField(form, 'username');
  const passwordValid = validateField(form, 'password');

  if (usernameValid && passwordValid) {
    console.log('form submitted');
    form.reset();
  }
});

inputsContainer.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  validateField(form, event.target.name);
});

function validateField(form, fieldName) {
  const errorEl = document.getElementById(`${fieldName}Error`);

  if (form.elements[fieldName].value == '') {
    errorEl.textContent = `${fieldName} is required`;
    return false;
  } else {
    errorEl.textContent = '';
    return true;
  }
}
```

```css
form div {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 200px;
}

form label { margin: 0 0 5px; }
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="formInputsContainer">
    <div>
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" />
      <span id="usernameError"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" />
      <span id="passwordError"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
    if(event.target.value==="" && document.querySelector('span') === null){
        event.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend','<span class="text-danger">Required</span>')
    }
    if(event.target.value!==""){
        var child=document.querySelector('span');
        child.remove();
    }
```

You only want to add a span IF the value is an empty string AND the span hsan't been added yet.

Comment: This will work only for one field as once the username span is added to will no longer be null and hence not work for password and confirm password fields.

Comment: Sure @SaraSameer  but you could select off of the ```target```... my intent was to provide guidance on the approach since there wasn't an answere when I saw the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which create a span which is add to the DOM with the `ID` which is based on the form element'sname attribute. And that element can be refered to based on the ID which was attach to it before It's been add to the DOM

```js
const checkinput=(event)=>{
    if(event.target.value===""){
        let spanId = `input-${event.target.name}`
        let span = `<span id="${spanId}" class="text-danger">Required</span>`
        setTimeout(() =>{
            document.getElementById(spanId).remove();
        }, 5000);
        event.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend',span)

    }
}
document.getElementById("username").addEventListener('blur',checkinput);
document.getElementById("password").addEventListener('blur',checkinput);
document.getElementById("confirmPassword").addEventListener('blur',checkinput);
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
  <input type="text" name="password" id="password"/>
  <input type="text" name="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

## May it help

```html
    <style>
      .errorMsg {
        border: 1px solid red;
      }
      .err {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
      <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      let nameTag = document.querySelector('#name');
      let passwordTag = document.querySelector('#password');
      let submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');

      nameTag.addEventListener('blur', e => validation(e));
      passwordTag.addEventListener('blur', e => validation(e));

      function validation(e) {
        if (e.target.value == '') {
          e.target.classList.add('errorMsg')
          submitBtn.setAttribute('disabled', true) // Disable submit that user cannot submit
          e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<span class="err ${e.target.id}">It is required</span>`) 
// In the above line we are inserting an element with class same as id of input that in the remove we remove a particular error message only
        } else {
          e.target.classList.remove('errorMsg')
          submitBtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
          document.querySelector(`.err.${e.target.id}`).remove();
//Here code is saying that the element with if 'err' and 'class same as id of input' if both class present then remove it 
        }
      }
    </script>
```

- Adding the class = id that a special error message delete

Comment: So basically, you have disabled the button as a whole. That's good too. but I was trying to prompt a span message to the user saying"required" as it is blurred out. So the user can detect which field has the problem. But thanking for contributing.

Comment: Please read answer code carefully If also containig the insertAdjacentElement()